# Httpd VirtualHosts with two IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7, virtualhost, httpd.conf

Two webapps must be accessed from their own IP (each one is dedicated to a network interface):

1. Webapp A is running on httpd server with php module, IP 142.xxx.xxx.xxx
2. Webapp B is running on tomcat7 server, IP 143.xxx.xxx.xxx

**httpd.conf**:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

NameVirtualHost 142.xxx.xxx.xxx:80  
NameVirtualHost 143.xxx.xxx.xxx:80

# Webapp A
<VirtualHost 142.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName ASite
    DocumentRoot /mnt/data/www/html
</VirtualHost>

# Webapp B
<VirtualHost 143.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName Bsite
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPass / http://www.siteb.com:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.siteb.com:8081/
    #<Proxy *>
    #   Order deny,allow
    #   Deny from all
    #   Allow from 54.171.140.42
    #</Proxy>   
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem: whatever ip/dns origin is typed, the endpoint is always site A, except if Webapp B is configured with   `<VirtualHost *:80>` which redirects (proxy on) all requests to tomcat webapp B. How to map the redirection accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was related to IP assignment in VirtualHost's directive (httpd resolves upon server's name instead) :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Webapp A
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ASite
    DocumentRoot /mnt/data/www/html
</VirtualHost>

# Webapp B
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Bsite
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
```